# Custom dialog in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog

I have in my app a class which extends ListFragment. I want to show a simple dialog with the options "Edit" and "Delete" (as Textviews) when long-clicking the list items. Unfortunately, my dialog crashes while instantiating the Textviews.
Here's my code:
In MyListFragment class:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedState);

    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int arg2, long arg3) {

            showDialog();
            return true;
        }
    });
}



protected void showDialog(){

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    TextView edit = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.edit);
    TextView delete = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.delete);


    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Do something

        }
    });
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             //Do something

        }
    });



    dialog.show();
};
```

The dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/dialog"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dialog_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dialog_padding"
    >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/edit"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_row_height"
      android:paddingTop="20dp"
      android:paddingBottom="20dp"
      android:paddingLeft="6dp"
      android:paddingRight="6dp"
      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
      android:text="@string/edit" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/delete"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_row_height"
      android:paddingTop="20dp"
      android:paddingBottom="20dp"
      android:paddingLeft="6dp"
      android:paddingRight="6dp"
      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
      android:text="@string/delete" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

The logcat says `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference` 
in fact, I checked via Log.d and the textview results null. 
I can't figure out why. I'm clearly missing something. 
Could you please help me understanding the cause of this issue? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`R.id.edit` and `R.id.delete` is not the part of the fragment is in dialog, so instead of getting the Edit and delete view from getView() you should get it from Dialog layout,

You can try this.

```
protected void showDialog(){

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    View view  = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    dialog.setContentView(view);

    TextView edit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    TextView delete = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete);


    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Do something

        }
    });
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Do something

        }
    });



    dialog.show();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried and I keep getting the same exception.

Comment: You changed like this, _TextView edit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit);_ instead of getView you changed to view and checked..?

Comment: Solved! The further issue was (if someone gets in trouble like I did) the app called the layout-v21 resource, which I forgot to update with the the textviews. Once fixed this, the code you suggested me works perfectly. Thank you @Muthukrishnan !!!!